# MySQL - Most efficient way to count relations

Tags: mysql, join, count, bigdata

I have two tables in MySQL. One with `accounts` (40 Million records) and one with `transactions` (300 Million records). There are around 200k transactions added daily. They have a 1:n relation:

```
+-----------------+
| Accounts        |
+----+------------+
| ID | account_no |
+----+------------+
```

and

```
+--------------------------------+
| Transactions                   |
+----+------------+--------+-...-+
| ID | account_no | amount | ... |
+----+------------+--------+-...-+
```

I need to write a SQL Query to create a list of `accounts` **ordered by amount of transactions**. So something like this comes to mind:

```
SELECT a.account_no , COUNT(a.account_no) tx_count FROM accounts a
INNER JOIN transactions tx ON a.account_no = tx.account_no
GROUP BY tx.account_no ORDER BY tx_count DESC LIMIT 1000;
```

([Link to SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd6bb2/11/0))

My Question: What is **the most efficient way** to achieve this, given that I have to deal with tens and hundreds of millions of records?

[Note: The field `account_no` is of course indexed]

Comment: what is the idea behind using limit but not order by ?

Comment: maybe better add new field like `transaction_amount` to `Accounts` table, update him with actual data of transactions, after this you don't need hard query. Of course you need update this field, if you will have new transactions.

Comment: @e4c5 Using `LIMIT` became a habit since I started working with huge amount of data ;) - I edited the question adding the `ORDER BY` which I had simply forgotten.

Comment: The most efficient way to deal with this is **not counting** records. How do you achieve this? By materializing the count. Every time you insert into `Transactions`, update the count in `Accounts` (let's say you created `trx_count int unsigned` field). When you delete from `Transactions`, reduce the count in `Accounts`. That way MySQL does work when it performs I/O, which is much more efficient than going through the entire data-set and counting rows.

Comment: @waki There are around 200k transactions added daily - I edited the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeking efficiency. So stick to one table, skipping the JOIN. And, use `COUNT(*)`. It counts raw rows. `COUNT(something_else)` needs to check `something_else` values for null before counting them.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cd6bb2/12/0)

```
 SELECT account_no, 
        COUNT(*) transaction_count
   FROM transactions
  GROUP BY account_no
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1000
```

It happens that the MyISAM access method can satisfy this query from the index directly. InnoDB will have to scan the index.

If your production report needs all the accounts summarized rather than just the top 1000, then you might consider omitting `ORDER BY COUNT(*)`.  That will save some time on the dbms.

The guys at Percona have lots of geeked-out explanations of how queries exploit indexes.  For example: https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/11/23/full-table-scan-vs-full-index-scan-performance/

Comment: the field `account_no` is indexed with InnoDB in the table `transactions` - Care to explain what "scan the index" means, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

To gain performance, you must do the least amount of work possible.

Performing a `COUNT(*)` doesn't fit that mantra.

Therefore, if you're after efficient way of obtaining the number you're after - don't use `COUNT(*)` at all. Simply create an integer field that contains the count number for particular record in `Account` and use triggers to handle incrementing/decrementing. It might sound that triggers will incur a performance penalty - they won't and the whole process becomes trivial while trying to obtain transaction count per account.

You can index the `trx_count` field and your queries become:

```
SELECT * FROM Accounts ORDER BY trx_count DESC;
```

### The table alteration:

```
ALTER TABLE Accounts add trx_count int unsigned  not null default '0';
```

### After insert trigger on `Transactions`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE

    TRIGGER `Transactions_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `Transactions` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        UPDATE Accounts SET trx_count = trx_count + 1 WHERE id = new.account_no;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

### After delete trigger on `Transactions`

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE

    TRIGGER `Transactions_after_delete` AFTER DELETE ON `Transactions` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
             UPDATE Accounts SET trx_count = trx_count - 1 WHERE id = old.account_no;
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Of course, this trades off `INSERT` performance for `SELECT` performance. It's possible the insert trigger will cause lags, especially if the 200K daily inserts are bunched together at certain times of day.

Comment: @OllieJones - not necessarily. Triggers are part of the transaction. While true that using a trigger will increase hdd bandwith spent (by a super small margin), the I/O will remain the same. Everything is a tradeoff, but in this case it's measurable which approach is the best. Small HDD bandwith and miniscule CPU time spent versus spending larger CPU time and larger bandwith + I/O - I believe that the choice is clear. But, as always, we can always measure and leave decisions to facts that we get from measuring :)